# UPDATE a row with the SUM() and COUNT() of other rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1111

Imagine two tables like:

```
t1: id, sum, cnt 
t2: id, id_t1, value
```

I want to do a query like this;

```
UPDATE t1, t2 
   SET t1.sum = SUM(t2.value), 
       t1.cnt = COUNT(*) 
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id_t1;
```

The query should update `t1.sum` with the sum of the values of `t2` where `t1.id=t2.id_t1` and `t1.count` with the count of rows there `t1.id=t2.id_t1`.

But fails and returns an error: `ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE: Invalid use of group function`

How should I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE  t1 a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  id_t1, 
                    SUM(value) totalSum,
                    COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    t2
            GROUP BY id_t1
        ) b ON   a.ID = b.id_t1
SET a.sum = COALESCE(b.totalSum, 0) ,
    a.cnt = COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/710b5/1)

Comment: I'm getting lots of deadlocks when using this query. How could I avoid them?

Comment: what do you mean by deadlocks? can you explain a little bit?

Comment: I'm using many concurrent connections to the server and the previous query is an INSERT on the same table. I solved the deadlock forcing to use the same connection for both operations. If you are curious, this is where I had the deadlocks: https://www.piratenpad.org/p/KqIjkA4NUC